# Profiles in pom.xml doesn't work when i use "-P" command

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, profile

I have a pom.xml with profiles like this:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>server1</id>
            <properties>
                <api.server.ip>serveraddr1</api.server.ip>
                <finalName>springboot</finalName>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>server2</id>
            <properties>
                <api.server.ip>serveraddr2</api.server.ip>
                <finalName>springbootnew</finalName>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

And i am trying to use it to set variable and make the name of jar

```
public static final String IP_ADDR="${api.server.ip}";
```

But when i use the command "mvn clean package -Pserver2", it doesn't work at all, neither the variable is set, nor the jar is named correctly.
And i find in IDEA it is like this:
[profiles in IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3fml.png)
I didn't see "MyProfile" anywhere. And it still doesn,t work when i trying to use IDEA to select profile.

tried command "mvn clean package -Pserver2" and selecting profile in IDEA

Comment: Don't. Don't use different maven profiles to build different artificats for different environments. Use spring profiles and just provide different `application.properties` for different environments.

Comment: But i use static variable in a ConstantUtil to set IP_ADDR, if i use properties the @value can't apply, and still i can't set the filename of the jar.

Comment: Don't use statics, use regular properties. Use/embrace the framework you are using instead of working around it.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I'd add another "don't". Don't use Spring profiles to choose between properties for different envs. A profile is an "if" in Spring context - you can create different _beans_ depending on the profile. Properties can be passed without any profiles - with system or env variables.

Comment: @Pulsar, today's Continuous Delivery mantra is "build once - deploy everywhere". You _really_ don't want to build multiple artifacts, and deploy a different binary on your test and prod environments. It has to be the same binary that's deployed on all envs. And then the env _configuration_ files (outside of the binary) define the different env properties.

Comment: Yes I'm very well aware that you can provide variables without profiles, nonetheless this is still being used in various ways. And yes doing different beans on profiles will also work. You could even provide no profiles and have an additional `application.properties` next to the jar that is being build. Fact is there are multiple ways of achieving this, which to do depends on your usecase. Another fact is that you shouldn't be building different deliverables for each environment.

Comment: ok i got how to fix it, thank u guys so much for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Maven profiles to read properties in your Java code. You can use them to filter resources that you can read in your Java code.

But as @M.Deinum already said, there are probably much better ways to achieve what you want to achieve.